# from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ConnectTimeout, ReadTimeout

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to execute the following code

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
```

but I am getting the error saying that

> from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ConnectTimeout,
>   ReadTimeout
>       ImportError: cannot import name ConnectTimeout

I have already installed requests, pandas_datareader
I am not sure where the problem is exactly. can someone help me on this?

I was trying to use Python shell aswell..

```
>>>import pandas_datareader

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .data import (get_components_yahoo, get_data_famafrench, get_data_google, get_data_yahoo, get_data_enigma,  # noqa
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.google.daily import GoogleDailyReader
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/google/daily.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.base import _DailyBaseReader
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 13, in <module>
from pandas_datareader._utils import (RemoteDataError, SymbolWarning,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/_utils.py", line 10, in <module>
import requests_ftp
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_ftp/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from .ftp import FTPAdapter, monkeypatch_session
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_ftp/ftp.py", line 13, in <module>
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ConnectTimeout,      ReadTimeout
ImportError: cannot import name ConnectTimeout
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you importing the modules from requests.exceptions?

Comment: What version of `requests` module do you have? I guess you want to update your `requests` module...

Comment: @Fruitspunchsamurai I am not using the modules from requests.exceptions yet. I was trying in normal python shell to check wether my imported package is working or not and I am stuck with this error.

Comment: @MaxU  requests==2.2.1 is the version I am using currently

Comment: @Bhargav, actual version of `requests` is `2.12.4` - `2.13`, version `2.2.1` ( Release date: `2014-01-23`) - so it's a little bit outdated. ;-) And what is your `pandas_reader.__version__`?

Comment: @MaxU I have updated to requests 2.12.4 , but still I am getting the same error. When I do pip freeze, the pandas-datareader version is 0.3.0.post0, but i am unable to import using python

Comment: @MaxU 
>>> import pandas_datareader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a pretty old version of `request` module.

Try to update it.

Comment: I have updated it too. But it was the same. I am using cloud9 for the development

Comment: can you post an output of the following: `import requests; print(requests.__version__)`? NOTE: you should use the same environment where you were executing: `from pandas_datareader import data, wb`

Comment: >>> import requests
>>> print (requests.__version__)
2.2.1

Answer (score -2):

I worked with the same requirements in normal virtualenv(with the same pip requirements) instead of working on cloud9. It worked. I guess this has something to do with the environmental platform.